# xaringan: generated table with nested formatted code

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, xaringan

In xaringan how to create table having some cells being formatted as code.
In markdown I would declare such table in a following way:

```
header1 | header2 | header3
---------------------------
`fun1` | `code1` | text not formatted as code
`fun2` | `code2` | another
`fun3` | `code3` | and again
```

Of course I do not except syntax highlighting.

I was able to use `knitr::kable(, format="html")` to produce table, but cannot make it work for formatting cells as code. Tried adding `<pre><code>fun1</code></pre>`, did not helped.

Comment: Can you please expand your sample code into a [mcve]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is super easy to fix. In your header bar you need to add vertical bars to ensure that it is rendered as a table:

```
header1 | header2 | header3
--------|---------|---------
`fun1` | `code1` | text not formatted as code
`fun2` | `code2` | another
`fun3` | `code3` | and again
```

Tables can be a little pernickety to get rendered correctly.

At least this gets the font right but the table css might override some of your default code layout.